# Про наследование в андроид

Tags: android, java

В общем, вопрос такой. Как известно, если класс Б наследуется от класса А, то классу Б будут доступны все методы из класса А, (кроме случая с private). В других языках везде так. А почему в Андроиде как-то по-другому понимается наследование. То есть если класс Б наследуется от класса А, а класс А запускается в начале программы, то если обратиться из класса А к классу Б, то класс Б сделает то же, что и класс А. То есть он тоже запустится и сделает все, что было написано в классе А. Ведь это неправильно. При наследовании только появляется возможность использовать методы из наследуемого класса. А тут получается, что Класс Б идентично выполняет всё, что написано в классе А.

В Классе А написан код, который выводит картинку, Класс Б, получается, тоже при запуске начинает выводить картинку.

Вот КОД http://ideone.com/10A8K8

Comment: Вообще, private методы и члены класса тоже наследуются.

Comment: А почему так?, допустим в C++ и java к методам и переменным с доступом private, могут обращаться только сам суперкласс, тоесть внутри класса. А тут получается что вообще все игнориться private protected public, без разницы все игнориться в android. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Покажите пример кода, который, по-вашему, работает нелогично. А то слишком много лишних слов

Comment: Я думаю вы чего-то не допоняли. Приведите конкретный пример кода. А то у Вас очень много букв и мало конкретики.

Comment: В андроиде нет наследования, андроид - это платформа. Вы, наверное, про язык программирования Java.

> то класс Б сделает тоже что и класс А.

то же, что и класс А

> Тоесть он тоже запуститься и сделает все что

То есть он тоже запустится и сделает все, что

> Ведь это не правильно. 

Ведь это неправильно.

Comment: @xTIGRx, а теперь было бы неплохо, если бы конкретно на приведенном вами коде вы бы пояснили, что именно в этом коде по-вашему неправильно/нелогично/непонятно, потому что из этого кода довольно непросто понять, что же именно вы подразумевали под классом А и классом В и как вообще ваш вопрос связан с этим кодом.

Comment: Переделал код. думаю тут понятнее будет
http://ideone.com/10A8K8
Вот почему в данной ситуации запускается в классе B приватный метод setTXT???

Comment: >Вот почему в данной ситуации запускается в классе B приватный метод setTXT???

так вы его внутри класса A выызываете, Внутри А он доступен

Comment: Запустите пожалуйста у себя на компьютере, то что он запускается в Классе А это и дураку понятно потому что он там прописан. Почему он запускается в классе Б. Ведь он доступен только классу А он же приватный

Comment: @xTIGRx я вам второй раз говорю - вы вызываете этот метод **только из класса А**. Вы его нигде не вызываете в классе В, не морочьте голову

Comment: По вашему я слепой чтоли? Текст "Привет" выводиться в классе B. Еще раз говорю запустите код на компьютере и вы сами все увидите.

Comment: @xTIGRx а теперь в третий раз - вы нигде (вот прям вообще-вообще нигде. Абсолютно нигде) не вызываете внутри класса B метод setTXT. Вы его (еще раз на всякий случай повторю) вызываете внутри класса А внутри его публичного метода onCreate. А метод onCreate класса А вы можете вызывать из B наследующегося от А класса, потому что этот метод публичный. Так надеюсь понятно?

Comment: @xTIGRx, что же по-вашему должно произойти при вызове `B.onCreate()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала, как уже было неоднократно отмечено, методы родительского класса `A`, будучи вызваны даже из производного класса `B`, ведут себя одинаково. Так что указываемое вами поведение правильно и имеет место в Java как под Android'ом, так и на всех других платформах. А также во всех других языках.

В комментариях прозвучал конструктивный вопрос: а что же делать? Как сделать так, чтобы метод `setTXT` не выполнялся в производном классе, а только в базовом?

Вот здесь возможны варианты. Самый простой концептуально — сделать метод `setTXT` не `private`, а `protected`, и *переопределить* (благо в Java методы по умолчанию виртуальные) этот метод в производном классе:

```
public class B extends A{
    @Override
    protected void setTXT() { }
}
```

Можно сделать и более просто, зато менее красиво: проверить точный тип класса в `setTXT`:

```
private void setTXT(){
    if (getClass() /* динамический тип */ != A.class /*статический тип*/) return;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Привет",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Единственный нормальный ответ.


Вот здесь возможны варианты. Самый простой концептуально — сделать метод setTXT не private, а protected, и переопределить (благо в Java методы по умолчанию виртуальные) этот метод в производном классе:

public class B extends A{
    @Override
    protected void setTXT() { }
}

Answer (score 5):

Допустим, есть два класса "A" и "B", "B" наследуется от "A", тогда созданный объект "b" будет так же являться и объектом "a", *"b" будет обладать всеми методами "a"*.

- Если у объекта "b" вызывается метод
  print(), который есть в классе "A", но
  которого нету в "B", то выполнится
  метод print() из класса "A".
- Если у объекта "b" вызывается метод
  print(), которого нету в классе "A",
  но который есть в "B", то выполнится
  метод print() из класса "B".
- Если у объекта "b" вызывается метод
  print(), который есть в классе "A" и в
  классе "B", то выполнится метод
  print() из класса "B". При этом в
  методе print() класса "B" можно
  вызвать print() из класса "A" (т.е.
  из суперкласса) через "super"
  ([ссылка](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)).

Всё это относится не к ОС, а к языку программирования, так что учите Java!

p.s. метод print() публичный, для понимания смысла модификаторов (и их отсутствия) лучше почитать книжку по java...

Comment: @DreamChild, но ведь метод onCreate невозможно сделать приватным, и как же тогда поступить, чтобы вызвать метод setTXT ТОЛЬКО В КЛАССЕ А. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: @xTIGRx: Будет, будет.

Модификаторы доступа в Java (да и во всех других известных мне языках) работают на лексическом уровне, во время компиляции, и управляют тем, что видно, а чего не видно. Во время выполнения они не существуют и не играют никакой роли.

(Ну хорошо, кое-какую роль играют для reflection'а.)

Comment: >Если вы такой знаток в ООП, то скажите, для чего, по-вашему, нужны модификаторы доступа?

Поменьше эмоций, пожалуйста. Вы, по всей вероятности, не очень понимаете принцип инкапсуляции данных в ООП (один из базовых принципов в данной концепции) и продолжаете упорно заблуждаться относительно того, как это работает, поэтому @ProkletyiPirat описал вам эти элементарные вещи, а не издевался над вами. Почитайте повнимательнее об инкапсуляции данных, и тогда, вероятно, все встанет на свои места.

Comment: @xTIGRx, вы слишком эмоциональны... успокойтесь, покурите, или попейте чаю с печенькой, в общем, отвлекитесь немного...

Что же касается возраста, то в интернете (и уж тем более на хешкоде) он не является аргументом, но если уж вам так интересно, то в данный момент мне 25 ...

Я уже ответил на ваш вопрос, но, по всей видимости, вы зациклились и зашли в ступор, отвлекитесь немного, а потом снова взгляните на свой код, вам будет очень смешно, когда осознаете причину своей проблемы :)

Answer (score 4):

Модификаторы private, protected, public являются определителями области видимости, а не области выполнения. Вы, я так понял, воспринимаете их как ограничения области выполнения. Если бы это было так, то какую реакцию на создания класса B вы ожидаете? А если этих методов много? Сделали прямого наследника, и все вызовы приватных методов в предке обнулились, что ли?

А как быть, если мы класс B приведём к классу A?

P.S. Да, а что происходит в С++ в такой ситуации? Мне кажется, то же самое, но было бы интересно увидеть код, который подтверждает Вашу логику на C++.

Comment: в С++ так же всё будет зависеть от наличия модификаторов (или их отсутствия). Если метод в родителе будет виртуальным, то будет то же, что и в java, если будет невиртуальным, то выскочит ошибка об отсутствии метода, разница языков в том, что в java все методы по умолчанию виртуальны, а в С++ - нет.

Comment: Я думаю, ошибки не будет в любом случае. Точнее, я знаю :-)